# In C++ Link list help ..show Record function started infinite loop

Tags: c++

I have coded a program where I implement **linklist(structure)** ,with two function `setRecord` for get IDs of the users and the second function is to show `ShowRecord()`
But when I entered IDs and then wanna show Record .. it just show first and last node or ...with some changes now it started infinite loop with last ID...
code is as follow...

```
// linklist practice.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct info
{
    int data;
    info *next;

};

void setRecord(info *temp);
void showRecord(info *temp);

int main()
{
    char a;
    info *base = new info;
    info *temp;
    info *last;
    temp = base;
    last = base;
    setRecord(temp);
    //do
//  {

        do
        {
            info *std = new info;
            std = last;
            temp->next = std;
            //std->next = NULL;
            setRecord(temp);
            temp->next = temp;
            cout << "Do you wanna Enter another....?(y or n):\n";
            cin >> a;
        } while (a =='y');
    //  break;
    //} while (1);
        last = NULL;
        showRecord(temp);
    system("pause");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void setRecord(info *temp)
{
    cout << "Enter your ID:->";
    cin >> temp->data;
}
void showRecord(info *temp)
{
    while (temp != NULL)
    {


            cout << "ID number "<< temp->data;
        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `do-while` loop is wrong. Try "drawing" (with arrows for pointers and rectangles for elements, for example) on a piece of paper what you're actually doing in the loop and what you need to do. This will help you do it the right way.

Comment: @KirilKirov I have done the paper work .. but actually I think the problem in showRecord function bellow .. what you think...because it does not show the record properly

Comment: What is the idea of `temp->next = std; setRecord(temp); temp->next = temp;`?

Comment: `showRecord` is perfectly fine. The problem is the `temp` you pass to it as argument. The `do-while` loop is the main problem for this.

Comment: @KirilKirov okay you are right .. problem with the argument .. show function is working problem thanks

Comment: @KirilKirov thanks a lot ..now it is working properly ..once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the `main()` method.

```
int main()
    {
        char a;
        info *base = new info;
        info *temp;
        info *first;
        temp = base;
        first=temp;
        setRecord(temp);
        //do
    //  {

            do
            {
                info *std = new info;

                temp->next = std;
                //std->next = NULL;
                temp=std;
                setRecord(temp);
                temp->next = null;
                cout << "Do you wanna Enter another....?(y or n):\n";
                cin >> a;
            } while (a =='y');
        //  break;
        //} while (1);
            showRecord(first);
        system("pause");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should show only the changes and explain why they solve the problem.